# How can I increase reference image quality?

Tags: image, customization

How can I increase the quality of reference images in Blender 2.8? The image I downloaded for reference is high quality, but after importing it as the reference image, it appears blurry when zoomed in. Is there any way to increase the image size in Blender?

Comment: Any image, outside of vector images, will appear blurry/pixelated when you zoom in. It sounds like you're dealing with a non-vector image here

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is for an obsolete version (2.8), but for Blender 3.2 I came across the same problem, that reference pictures appear too blurry.

For my case I found the solution how to increase the quality of reference pictures imported into Blender by going to

*Edit > Preferences > Viewport > Textures > Limit Size [x]*

If the texture size is too small, like in my case `256`, the reference picture will be blurry, pixelated and unusable. Increase x at least to `1024` or more and the quality of the reference pictures will increase as well. Blender treats them inside the viewport as any other texture.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure image is selected. Go to *Object Data* properties and change the color space from *sRGB* to *Linear*.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the *Add* menu in the *Sequencer Editor* and select *Image*.

Navigate to the location of your image file and select it.

In the *Add Image* dialog box, make sure the *Fit* option is unchecked.